# golang combination generation made an error

Tags: go

I'm dealing with a programming problem

> Given two integers n and k, return all possible combinations of k numbers out of 1 ... n.

and with input n = 5, k = 4, the output should be [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,4,5],[1,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5]], the following is my golang solution

```
func combine(n int, k int) [][]int {
    result := [][]int{}
    comb := []int{}
    subcom(0, k, n, &comb, &result)
    return result
}

func subcom(s, k, n int, comb *[]int, result *[][]int) {
    if k > 0 {
        for i := s + 1; i <= n-k+1; i++ {
            c := append(*comb, i)
            subcom(i, k-1, n, &c, result)
        }
    } else {
        *result = append(*result, *comb)
    }
}
```

I think my solution is right, but it return [[1 2 3 5] [1 2 3 5] [1 2 4 5] [1 3 4 5] [2 3 4 5]].

After debugging, I found [1 2 3 4] was added to the result slice at the beginning, but later changed to [1 2 3 5], resulting in the repetition of two [1 2 3 5]s. But I can't figure out what's wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common mistake when using `append`.

When your code runs `c:=append(*comb,i)`, it tries to first use the allocated memory in the underlying array to add a new item and only create a new slice when it failed to do so. This is what changes the `[1 2 3 4]` to `[1 2 3 5]` - because they share the same underlying memory.

To fix this, copy when you want to append into result:

```
now := make([]int,len(*comb))
copy(now,*comb)
*result = append(*result,now)
```

Or use a shortcut of copying:

```
*result = append(*result, append([]int{},*comb...))
```

Update:

To understand what I mean by underlying memory, one should understandd the internal model of Go's slice.

In Go, a slice has a data structure called `SliceHeader` which is accessible through `reflect` package and is what being referred to when you use `unsafe.Sizeof` and taking address.

The `SliceHeader` taking cares of three elements: `Len`,`Cap` and a `Ptr`. The fisrt two is trivail: they are what `len()` and `cap()` is for. The last one is a `uintptr` that points to the memory of the data the slice is containing.

When you shallow-copy a slice, a new `SliceHeader` is created but with the same content, including `Ptr`. So the underlying memory is not copied, but shared.

Comment: do you mean `c:=append(*comb, i)` add i to comb firstly, and then decide whether it's necessary to create a new slice for c?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the blog, I have finished reading it, and it helps a lot. But one more thing, when I print the address of the slices in result:

`0xc000018260ath, 0xc000018260ath, 0xc000018280ath, 0xc0000182a0ath, 0xc0000182c0ath`

the first and the second shared the same address, but others did not, I can't figure   out the reason

Comment: @kasheemlew I have updated my answer to address that.